# Image carousel/slideshow for images in rows in ag-grid in agular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm a beginner to angular and ag-grid and any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to add a carousel/slideshow for images in the rows/fields for the ag-grid table that I have, and confused how to implement that without using a library for the carousel but if I have to then I can try that too.

Expected functionality. ag-grid table consists of values like image, id, etc.. and I want to add a carousel for the images in the pop-up modal for the images.

Any help will be appreciated, even to get me started. Thanks!

Comment: start by making the pop-up modal, you will quickly find out that when you have the modal its a seperate component, and you can focus on added a carousel in that.

Comment: thought that being said, before posting questions on stackoverflow you should at least show what you tried and failed.

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about is how to pull data from the next row